# Error response graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/manager

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

Look at my code, what am I doing wrong? I need to get [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${uniqueName}/manager](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$%7BuniqueName%7D/manager). But the request fails
But when I try to execute the [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/${uniqueName}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$%7BuniqueName%7D) query, everything goes well. What to fix so that the [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${uniqueName}/manager](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$%7BuniqueName%7D/manager) request is successful?

```
fastify.post('/login', {
    preHandler: (request, _, next) => {
      if (!request.body || !request.body.username || !request.body.password) {
        const error = new Error('Credentials are missing');
        error.statusCode = 400;

        return next(error);
      }

      return next();
    },
  }, async (request, reply) => {
    const { username, password } = request.body;
    const userData = await fastify.helpers.authentication.getUserTokens(username, password, azureConfig.CLIENT_SCOPE);
    await replyWithTokens(fastify, reply, userData);
  });
```

And next

```
const getUserTokens = async (username, password, scope) => {
  const authUrl = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${azureConfig.TENANT_NAME}/oauth2/v2.0/token`;
  const body = {
    client_id: azureConfig.CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret: azureConfig.CLIENT_SECRET,
    grant_type: 'password',
    password,
    scope,
    username,
  };
  const authResponse = await fetch(authUrl, {
    body: new URLSearchParams(body).toString(),
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    method: 'POST',
  });

  if (!authResponse.ok) {
    fastify.helpers.error.throwError(422, 'Authentication failed');
  }

  const result = await authResponse.json();
  const decodedData = jwt.decode(result.access_token);
  const uniqueName = String(decodedData.unique_name || '').toLowerCase();
  const name = String(decodedData.upn || uniqueName).toLowerCase();
  const agentAttributes = {};

  if (!uniqueName) {
    fastify.helpers.error.throwError(400, 'Unique name not found');
  }

  let recheckSan = true;
  let san = name.split('@').shift();
  let agent = await fastify.db.models.Agent.findOne({
    where: { uniqueName },
  });
  let radId = '';
  const graphAuthResponse = await fetch(authUrl, {
    body: new URLSearchParams({
      ...body,
      scope: 'email openid profile https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read',
    }).toString(),
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    method: 'POST',
  });

  if (graphAuthResponse.ok) {
    const graphAuthResult = await graphAuthResponse.json();
    const { access_token: graphAccessToken = '' } = graphAuthResult;

    // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
    const graphResponse = await fetch(`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${uniqueName}/manager`, {
      headers: {
        authorization: `Bearer ${graphAccessToken}`,
        'content-type': 'application/json',
      },
    });

    if (graphResponse.ok) {
      const graphResult = await graphResponse.json();
      console.log(graphResult)
    }
  }
}
```

I want to receive such response

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#directoryObjects/$entity",
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
    "id": "1111112-68cf-4896-b2d0-13b5c6264113",
    "businessPhones": [
        "111 111 11111"
    ],
    "displayName": "Wer, John",
    "givenName": "John",
    "jobTitle": "SENIOR DEVELOPMENT ARCHITECT",
    "mail": "somemail@mail.com",
    "mobilePhone": "111 111 1111",
    "officeLocation": "Atlanta",
    "preferredLanguage": null,
    "surname": "John",
    "userPrincipalName": "somemail@mail.com"
}
```

But I get such an error response. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
        "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-01-14T20:40:30",
            "request-id": "9e2b5937-4bd0-4fdb-a1ae-1b22cef09772",
            "client-request-id": "9e2b5937-4bd0-4fdb-a1ae-1b22cef09772"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think `User.Read` restricts the app to read basic information for the user only. It does not include the privilege to read their manager's info. For that purpose, you would be required to use `User.Read.All` permission. More details can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#remarks-28).

Comment: If I set up such permission  User.Read.All, then I can’t even get a token, such an error
  [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
    url: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/elnk.com/oauth2/v2.0/token',
    status: 400,
    statusText: 'Bad Request',
    headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] },
    counter: 0

Comment: I am guessing from the code that you are using resource-owner password credential grant workflow. The client app (as registered in Azure AD) used for this purpose is required to have `User.Read.All` delegated permissions in the menu for `API permissions` (in Azure AD > Application registrations > YourClientApp). Given ROPC is non-interactive, the admin must grant consent for all users for the `User.Read.All` delegated permission.

Comment: thanks! it really helped me

Answer (score 0):

To get the managers of other users in your organization on your behalf, you need to have **User.Read.All**  delegated permission

[image]

Once the permission is assigned, admin consent needs to be granted for the same.

Then you would be able to fetch the managers info of other users in your organization

You can test the same in Graph Explorer first. If it is successful, you can make the changes accordingly in your JavaScript code

Comment: thanks! it really helped me

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you